# Alternative to Facebook read_stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

Is there an alternative to allowing the permissions of some sort rather then 'read_stream' permission in Facebook, for a user to read or an app pull their Facebook feed or home feed?

It's very hard, if at all, for Facebook to approve the 'read_stream' permission, so I'm looking for an alternative steps to still allow for our users to pull their favorite stories in our rails app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative. You can use `user_status` to get the status posts of the authorized user with `/me/statuses`.

Btw, it´s not only "hard" to get `read_stream` approved, it´s nearly impossible ;) - but for very good reasons. Apps should not get access to posts of users who did not even authorize the App.

edit: There is also `user_posts` now, as replacement for `read_stream`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_new_features

Comment: It seems that only `/me/statuses` and `/me/links` are left. The photos/videos need extra permission, and they don't include the privacy information (strangely enough).  I find it strange that an user can't get access to their own posted content anymore, makes the`user/feed push notifications also rather pointless.

Comment: well, a user CAN get access. he can only not get access to the posts of his friends, which is a very good thing.

Comment: you mean it is possible to access `/me/feed` ? Without `read_stream` permission? From the docs it seems that you will always need that permission.  **update: just checked in the graph explorer: `/me/feed` is not available without `read_stream` permission.

Comment: no, of course not. you need read_stream for /me/feed, as you read correctly. that´s not at all what i meant...

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to me. It shouldn't be hard to get a filtered stream of the user's own posts. To me the privacy aspect is just a red herring - I suspect FB is slowly closing access for non-FB authorized apps/sites. Just like LinkedIn just did with their API.

Comment: users own posts are with /me/statuses, as i wrote in my answer. it´s actually great how they improved it. linked in still works fine, only some specific endpoints (for example, to get access to second level connections) need approval. but it´s not that hard to get approved afaik. but that´s way beyond the topic of this thread, and it´s senseless to rant about facebook. it´s their api, so they can do whatever they want with it ;)

Comment: The `/me/statuses` only shows statuses. The links, photos and videos are not included. The `/me/photos/uploaded` (from the top of my head) can be used for the photos, but it doesn't include any privacy information about the photos.  BTW I only "rant" a bit because it is the user's data :) It is indeed up to FB to decide what they do and where they go, maybe leaving opportunities for others.

Comment: I just don't see how a user who approves a 'read_stream' permission, shouldn't be able to use another app other then Facebook. I know about 5 apps, that dropped Facebook, because of it and that's possible a lot of user loss too for the apps. The point is, if I post something or my friend posts something to me on my feed, and I go to an app of whatever and tell that app, its fine of you read my feed, Facebook should simply butt out. Can't even list things I liked anymore in app, other the pages I liked because Facebook took that as well. Its pointless for Facebook to be doing this; true colors?

Comment: I should at least be able to authorize and see my wall of stuff; things I liked, shared, collected, etc... from other apps then Facebook. Just saying.

Comment: well, it is how it is, if you like it or not. but as i said, it does make sense, because if a user authorizes an app, why should the app get access to posts of friends too? that´s just wrong. and if you read my answer, it IS possible to read your OWN stuff. you don´t need read_stream for that.

Comment: Just tried the Graph API Explorer, and it tells me that for  `/me/links` the `read_stream` permission is needed. It also says so for `/me/statuses` but it clearly returns data if `user_status` has been allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Did some investigation. And it is possible.

Instead of the feed you need to access the endpoint `/me/posts`
This API is accessible with either `read_stream` or `user_posts` permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_posts

See here for more information:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

It is quite hidden, but if you know where to look you can find the docs.